# C# WinForms & SQL Server : how to render image in gridview using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xBkj.png)How to render an image in a Gridview using stored procedure?

Currently what is showing in the gridview is the path (location) of image or folder, but I need to render the image itself - that first column must become an image column.  This is for Windows Forms using C#. Thanks for the help.

[image showing image paths instead of actual images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBoqQ.png)

```
void FillDataGridView_Main()
{
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("[sp_selectTop10CycleTime]", sqlCon);
    sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
    sqlDA.Fill(dataTbl);

    dgvNextCycleTime.DataSource = dataTbl;

    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Now working with the given codes below :)
But encounter another error when using timer to update every 1 second the void FillDataGirdView_Main()

```
 void FillDataGridView_Main()
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("[sp_selectTop10CycleTime]", sqlCon);
        sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDA.Fill(dataTbl);
        dgvNextCycleTime.DataSource = dataTbl;
        sqlCon.Close();

        int ImagePathIndex = 0; // assuming that the image path  column is 0 (See in your case) 
        dgvNextCycleTime.Columns[ImagePathIndex].Visible = false; // Make visibility for the path = false

        DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColunm = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        ImageColunm.HeaderText = "Image";
        ImageColunm.Name = "ImageName";
        ImageColunm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
        ImageColunm.Image = null;
        dgvNextCycleTime.Columns.Insert(1, ImageColunm); // Add the new colunm to the grid 

        // Add the image to the new column in the grid
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvNextCycleTime.Rows)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(row.Cells[ImagePathIndex].Value.ToString());
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells["ImageName"] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cell.Value = img;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add new column for the image and make the image path visibility = false

so your code will be like that :-

```
sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("[sp_selectTop10CycleTime]", sqlCon);
        sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());


        DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();


        sqlDA.Fill(dataTbl);

        dgvNextCycleTime.DataSource = dataTbl;

        sqlCon.Close();
        //////////////////////////////// New code ////////////////////////////
        int ImagePathIndex = 0; // assuming that the image path  column is 0 (See in your case) 
        dgvNextCycleTime.Columns[ImagePathIndex].Visible = false; // Make visibility for the path = false

        DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColunm = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        ImageColunm.HeaderText = "Image";
        ImageColunm.Name = "ImageName";
        ImageColunm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
        ImageColunm.Image = null;
        dgvNextCycleTime.Columns.Add(ImageColunm); // Add the new colunm to the grid 


        // Add the image to the new column in the grid
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvNextCycleTime.Rows)
        {

            Image img = Image.FromFile(row.Cells[ImagePathIndex].Value.ToString());
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells["ImageName"] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cell.Value = img;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Hassan Badry, I updated the questions..  I encounter error using TImer but without timer, it's smooth.. please help.

Comment: I think there's a problem encountered in the foreach loop?
Tried to debug, when the loop ends and try to start the loop again, there's an error pointing to first line of foreach loop.  Hope you can help me solve this please

Comment: Well then try to remove this lines from the code :-


 DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColunm = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        ImageColunm.HeaderText = "Image";
        ImageColunm.Name = "ImageName";
        ImageColunm.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
        ImageColunm.Image = null;
        dgvNextCycleTime.Columns.Insert(1, ImageColunm); 



and put them in form load instead

Comment: Applied what you instructed but error prompted in the formload pointing  to dgvNextCycleTime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved the path into the database, you could use `DataGridViewImageColumn`' and `CellFormatting` event to load the image.

You can view sample in last post of page here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e676b21-fa8b-4e35-ba22-b7c7f9963593/image-retrieving-from-sql-to-data-gridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, put `DataGridView` control on your form and define columns. In my example, there are two columns where first one is used for showing image (column type `DataGridViewImageColumn`) and second one is text column (type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`), as in this image:

[image]

In code, after you used your stored procedure to load data into `DataTable`, iterate through rows and create those rows in your `dgvNextCycleTime` control, something like this:

```
//this is my test data, you should start with foreach line
DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
dataTbl.Columns.Add("ImageColumn", typeof(string));
dataTbl.Columns.Add("SecondColumn", typeof(string));

dataTbl.Rows.Add(new string[] { @"c:\temp\img1.png", "some title" });
dataTbl.Rows.Add(new string[] { @"c:\temp\img2.png", "some title2" });

//here you need to go through every row in DataTable, create Image object from path
foreach (DataRow row in dataTbl.Rows)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(row[0].ToString()); //be sure you're getting path from correct column (first one in my example)
    dgvNextCycleTime.Rows.Add(new object[] { img, row[1].ToString() }); //second column, with some text
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nino, this is working.  But I updated the question..  please help.
Using the timer to update the gridview everysecond, there was prompted error.

Thank you

Comment: I think there's a problem encountered in the foreach loop?
Tried to debug, when the loop ends and try to start the loop again, there's an error pointing to first line of foreach loop.  Hope you can help me solve this please